# how to output something like <this is my word="word" value="#abcg#"> using cfoutput coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfoutput

how to output something like   using cfoutput tag.

```
     <cfoutput>
         <this is my word="word" value="#abcg#">
     </cfoutput>
```

this will gives me nothing when i use single-quote it will print it with single-quote like

```
     <cfoutput>
        <'this is my word="word" value="#abcg#"'>
     </cfoutput>
```

result is:

```
      <'this is my word="word" value="#abcg#"'>
```

how can i get just

```
    <this is my word="word" value="#abcg#">
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Are the angle brackets part of the string you are attempting to print?

Comment: Most browsers are going to see the "<" and ">" and consider them HTML containers with unknown tags.

Comment: yes with the angle brackets

Comment: with <pre> tag the output is different it breaks the line after printing the opening angle bracket

Comment: Do you want `#abcg#` shown on the screen, or the value of #abcg# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to escape the browser trying to render it as an HTML tag

```
<cfoutput>
    &lt;this is my word="word" value="#abcg#"&gt;
 </cfoutput>
```